# nowPlayingItem + 1 does not always play the next song

Tags: swift, collections, mpmusicplayercontroller

I have the following code set to run every time a certain button is pressed.  For the first several songs nowPlayingInt rolls by 1, then it jumps from 7 to 10, then rolls by 3 each time, then jumps from 13 to 17 and starts rolling by 4 each time.  Any thoughts as to how or why nowPlayingInt can vary by more than just 1 as the musicPlayer steps through songs?

```
    let nowPlayingInt = delegate.queryAsCollection!.items.indexOf(delegate.musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem!)
    print("nowPlayingInt number is \(nowPlayingInt)")
    delegate.musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem = delegate.queryAsCollection!.items[nowPlayingInt! + 1]
```

I'm aware that I could use .skipToNextItem but that's not what I'm trying to do and wouldn't help me if I wanted to skip more than 1 song.

AppDelegate contains:

```
let musicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer()    
var queryAsCollection : MPMediaItemCollection?
var collectionForNextUps = MPMediaQuery()
```

Comment: Could you share the code for your delegate implementation?

Comment: @kye  I updated the code so that both lines use queryAsCollection.  I also added the AppDelegate contents...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got `indexofNowPlayingItem` to work as desired.  Still not sure why the line with `indexOf` didn't do the trick but I thought I'd post the answer for at least a shot at completeness.

```
    let nowPlayingInt = delegate.musicPlayer.indexOfNowPlayingItem
    print("nowPlayingInt number is \(nowPlayingInt)  1  ")
    delegate.musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem = delegate.queryAsCollection!.items[nowPlayingInt + 1]
```